# C# WPF and Sqlite: Datagrid displays last table recording when trying to read from an sqlite database table

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, datagrid, observablecollection

I can't figure why my data grid is displaying the last table recording from an Sqlite database. 
here is the code I've writen.

```
    ObservableCollection<Activity> _activitiesList = new ObservableCollection<Activity>();



  while (reader.Read())
{
   _act.Name = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Activity"));
   _act.Customer = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("ActivityCustomer"));
   _act.Activitytpe = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("ActivityNature"));
   string st = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("StartedAt"));
   _act.StartedAt = Convert.ToDateTime(st);
   string et = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("FinishedAt"));
   _act.EndedAt = Convert.ToDateTime(et);
   //string _ratio = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("ActivityRatio"));
   //_act.ActivityRatio = Convert.ToDouble(_ratio);
   _act.Notes = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Notes"));
   string _hldy = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Holiday"));
   _act.IsHoliday = Convert.ToBoolean(_hldy);
   _activitiesList.Add(_act);
}
ActivitiesDataGrid.ItemsSource=_activitiesList;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you create new object instance for "Activity" class in inside while loop.

```
 ObservableCollection<Activity> _activitiesList = new ObservableCollection<Activity>();

**while (reader.Read())
            {
                ***_act = new Activity();***
                _act.Name = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Activity"));
               ....
               ....
             }**
```

Comment: Thanks. I've added a new object instance for activity in the while loop and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

inside the while you have to instantiate a new activity class:

```
while (reader.Read())
{ 
      Activity _act=new Activity();
      ....
}
```